# MalformedURLException does not care for correctness of URL besides correctness of protocol (scheme) ? Why?

Tags: java, url, uri

These compile and *run* without `MalformedURLException`:

```
new URL("http://example.com/dir1/dir2/page1.html&k>v%k1=>v^!");

new URL("http:////\\example\\.com/dir1/\\@dir2/@&##page1.html&k>v%k1=>v^!");
```

[API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-) for `URL(String spec)` constructor writes

> MalformedURLException - if **no protocol is specified**, or an **unknown protocol** is found, or **spec is null**.

So it checks only argument for not-null and if it is not null - one more check for correct/existing protocol (scheme).

URI constructors are different - they throw `java.net.URISyntaxException` at runtime in both cases, detecting illegal characters.

1) Why MalformedURLException is so much limited to just checking protocol? This is misleading as to its name "Malformed URL"...

2) Shall I always prefer using URI over using URL and is URL left just for legacy/compatibility reasons?